# Native Python Editor for Mac?

Tags: python, macos, ide, editor, python-idle

I'm currently using IDLE, its decent, but I'd like to know if there're better lightweight IDEs built especially for Mac — free or commercial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[TextMate](http://macromates.com/) is a great general-purpose editor for mac. Used by the Rails community a lot, but it's great with python too.

Comment: But Textmate is not 100% compatible with Snow Leopard yet. :(

Comment: I've yet to have an issue with it...

Comment: I've had 0 problems with TextMate and Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 3):

Allow me to suggest the GUI version of [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) for Mac OS X, aptly named [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/).  It is superb.

Answer (score 2):

Purpose built for Mac? [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) supports python. [Textmate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textmate) and [BBEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBedit) are also great editors.

If you're fine with generic multiplatform IDE's, [Komodo Edit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komodo_Edit#Komodo_Edit) is great.

Answer (score 2):

So, I was using **TextMate** for a while for python. It is good for writing small programs but not for managing big projects. I ran into problems, especially sometimes it caused mismatched indentations. For the life of me, I was not able to figure out what was going on. Then I switched to **BBEdit**, and it helped me a lot. It figures out indentation by itself, gives code completion like xcode, is fairly fast. Unfortunately, it is not a free download. The free version **textwrangler** should have similar features, however, I have not used it.

Another good option is [Spyder](https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/). It is made for scientific computing. It basically gives you a MATLAB like IDE for python. And it is free and open source. Install through MacPorts.

By the way, TextMate is now a free download. https://github.com/textmate/textmate

Answer (score 1):

There is a commercial one - Textmate.
Most of the good free editors are cross-platform (if you are ok with it, I'd recommend EditRa - but it doesn't work properly under 10.6 yet, because of some bugs in wxPython).

Answer (score 1):

There're aren't any Mac-specific Python IDEs, though [Komodo's](http://www.activestate.com/komodo/) IDE, [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/features/python/index.html) and Eclipse (with the excellent [PyDev](http://pydev.sourceforge.net/) extensions) all have very good Python IDE functionality and run fine on OS X. I've never used [Wing](http://www.wingware.com/) IDE on OS X, but it has a pretty loyal following as well. If you just need an editor (I find that a good editor and a command line are often sufficient for Python), [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) along with [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org) in a terminal is the way to go. When I really do need a full IDE, I've been very happy with Eclipse/PyDev.

Answer (score 0):

vim, emacs, BBEdit, WingIDE, or my favorite - eclipse (although, I don't think this is very lightweight)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to look at **Aptana**(it's more attractive then Eclipse for me)**+PyDev** or **PyCarm**. I use **TextMate** too, but those are easy for debug.

Answer (score 0):

I use **FRAISE** (free) it is *simple* and useful, auto indentation, colorize, auto completion, shell.

Answer (score 0):

going to vote for Fraise. handles almost anything, has indentations, and uses color! its free too.

Answer (score 0):

check out Sublime Text 2 Alpha. seriously awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I really like [Coderunner](https://coderunnerapp.com) for casual programming. It's beautiful!